# External keyboard’s Trackpoint middle button clicks even when scrolling

Tags: mouse, scrolling, trackpoint, xinput

I am using a Thinkpad and try to get into the habit of using an external keyboard, which also has a Trackpoint.

With the internal keyboard, I can use the middle mouse button to click (e.g. paste, or open link in new tab), but if I hold the middle button and move the Trackpoing, I am scrolling.

For the external keyboard, I am observing that scrolling works, but it also often (not always) issues a click event, and suddenly my editor is full of pasted stuff

The `xinput` properties seem to be set the same:

Internal:

```
~ $ xinput list-props 16
Device 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (325):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (326):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (330): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (331): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (332):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (333):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (358):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (359):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (334): -0.500000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (335): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (336):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (337):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (338):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (339): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (340): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (310): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (311):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (312):    0, 0
    Device Node (313):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Device Product ID (314):    2, 10
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (341):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (342):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (343):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (344):    15
```

External

```
~ $ xinput list-props 18
Device 'Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II Mouse':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (325):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (326):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (330): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (331): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (332):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (333):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (358):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (359):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (334): -0.500000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (335): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (336):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (337):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (338):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (339): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (340): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (310): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (311):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (312):    0, 0
    Device Node (313):  "/dev/input/event19"
    Device Product ID (314):    6127, 24814
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (341):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (342):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (343):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (344):    15
```

Where else should I look? Is this “Customer Control” device relevant?

```
~ $ xinput list-props 20
Device 'Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II Consumer Control':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (325):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (326):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (310): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (311):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (312):    0, 0
    Device Node (313):  "/dev/input/event21"
    Device Product ID (314):    6127, 24814
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (341):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (342):   1
```

Comment: Also posted at <https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2022-April/060945.html> now; if something comes up there I’ll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a bug in the Linux Kernel, fixed by [a patch by
José Expósito which](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-input/20220401115726.6pp2avtl5ezqkbr2@tp/T/#u) which is part of the Linux 5.19 release.